# How to define a class variable in Flow so that it extends another type?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

```js
// @flow
class Demo {
    SomeError: Error
  
    constructor() {
        this.SomeError = class extends Error {
            constructor(message: string) {
                super(message)
                this.name = 'SomeError'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have been trying to do something like that. But flow gives an error: `Cannot assign 'class { ... }' to 'this.SomeError' because class '<<anonymous class>>' [1] is incompatible with 'Error'`. The temporary and ugly solution for me to write the class variable as:

```js
// ...
ErrorClass: Object
// ...
```

I don't understand why it accepts Object as a type but not Error. Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `: Error` represents instance of class `Error`, not the class itself/constructor. To get the constructor type you can use `typeof` operator:

```
class Demo {
    SomeError: typeof Error
  
    constructor() {
        this.SomeError = class extends Error {
            constructor(message: string) {
                super(message)
                this.name = 'SomeError'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiDG0CGBnToAiBTAW1lAG9FRLQBlWQ-AUQCcnYmAuUAFwE8AHfLEihmrJhVATKKWADtMXJgFcUXNgAoAlGSlVKXABYBLTADpa9UW1ABeUGiw58ADy75ZAExxWmOvf6oZeUUVNSZ1emx0AHN8TgUmI1lo7XIA9KpMJQFwyMwY-E1dDL1DE1NZdHpbUAByC0YWNlri9IBfVsoOvQ62oA)

---

Other option is to use [`Class`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-class) utility.

> Given a type `T` representing instances of a class `C`, the type `Class<T>` is the type of the class `C`

```
class Demo {
    SomeError: Class<Error>
  
    constructor() {
        this.SomeError = class extends Error {
            constructor(message: string) {
                super(message)
                this.name = 'SomeError'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiDG0CGBnToAiBTAW1lAG9FRLQBlWQ-AUQCcnYmAuUAYQ2wB5mrJgD4KoMZRSwAdpgAuTAK4o5bABQBKMhKqU5ACwCWmAHS16gtqAC8oNFhz4AHnPzSAJjktNtuv1SlZBWVVJjV6bHQAc3xOeSZDaSitcn80qkxFAAd8MIjMaPwNHXTdA2MTaXR6G1AAcnNGFjY6krSAXzbKTt1O9qA)

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Also adding `Class<T>` is an alias for `new<T>(): T`.